# Qual a diferença entre definir um model como interface ou como class no IONIC?

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic3

Sou um iniciante na programação e a minha linguagem de entrada é o Java.

Estudando alguns projetos com Ionic, encontrei um que usava uma interface para definir um model, por exemplo:

```
export interface Pessoa {
   nome: string;
   idade: number;
 }
```

Lembro que a diferença básica entre uma classe e uma interface é que a interface não implementa comportamentos.

Sei que o Ionic é baseado em TypeScript. Qual a razão de adotar essa prática?

Sei que TypeScript não é Java mas como o Java é a minha referência, onde deve ficar os métodos da classe (ou interface) Pessoa em Ionic?

Answer (score 1):

No link abaixo existe um tutorial mais aprofundado sobre a questão.

https://showmethecode.com.br/typescript-classes-vs-interfaces/

Mas resumidamente, se deseja um modelo que possua apenas atributos e nenhum método, utilize uma interface. Caso contrário, crie uma classe para implementar métodos.

Mas lembrando que mesmo assim, uma interface pode ser estendida em uma classe.